Dompdf not rendering display: flex correctly in generated PDF
I'm using Dompdf to generate PDF invoices from HTML templates in my PHP application. The HTML/CSS template includes display: flex for layout purposes, but when rendered into a PDF using Dompdf, the display: flex does not behave as expected. Instead, elements are not laid out correctly or appear misaligned.
I've verified that the HTML and CSS work correctly in web browsers, and the issue seems to be specific to Dompdf's rendering engine. Here's a simplified version of my code:
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

// Initialize Dompdf
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$html = '<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
        }
        .item {
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>';

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('output.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));

Here's how the layout looks on the website:
Website Layout
And here's how it looks in the generated PDF:
Generated PDF Layout
What I've tried:
Simplifying the CSS and HTML to basic elements.
Checking Dompdf documentation and CSS compatibility.
Ensuring all required PHP extensions (php-mongodb, php-zip, php-gd, php-dom) are installed and up to date.

According to their GitHub repo, "dompdf is (mostly) a CSS 2.1 compliant HTML layout and rendering engine", and that version did not include flexbox or grid. Lack of flexbox support is even called out in their "Limitations" area.

This is a common issue because Dompdf's CSS support is limited, particularly for modern layout features like flexbox. Maybe you can try either of the alternatives below:

Use display: inline-block with proper font-size management for consistent horizontal alignment.
Use table-based layout (display: table/table-cell) which has excellent support in Dompdf.
Consider using a third-party HTML-to-PDF API like PageSnap (https://pagesnap.co) that uses Puppeteer/Chrome for rendering, which will support all modern CSS features including flexbox.

Consider chosing option 1 or 2 if you want to stick with Dompdf, or option 3 if you need full CSS support and can use an external service.
